# While trying to encode a pointcloud I keep getting the same errors. I have tried to changing my environment and updating Glibcxx version and yet

Tags: linux, encoding, anaconda, point-clouds, libstdc++

```
$ python vmuc.py compress /home2/kubra/JPEG/Stanford_Area_2.ply ../models/Geometry-only/Codec/0.00025/checkpoint_best_loss.pth.tar ../results/G0.00025
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/kubra/JPEG/JPEG_PCC_VM/jpeg-pleno-pc-vm-main/src/vmuc.py", line 13, in <module>
    import loss_functions
  File "/home2/kubra/JPEG/JPEG_PCC_VM/jpeg-pleno-pc-vm-main/src/loss_functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .fixes import parse_version, threadpool_info
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 19, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 467, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 39, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from ._kdtree import *
  File "/home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_kdtree.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._ckdtree import cKDTree, cKDTreeNode
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_ckdtree.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)``
```

I'm currently working on point clouds codec. I tried encoding a point cloud but I keep getting the same error:

```
"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/kubra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/\_ckdtree.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)"
```

It says, apparently the version of GLIBCXX is not found whatsoever.. I tried updating my libstdc, creating new env with updated packages etc but it didnt workk for me. I have no idea  of why it doesn't work and what I need to do. Could anyone please tell me what should I do?

Comment: DLL issues often result from mixing channels. Try recreating the environment with clear channel priorities (e.g., try sourcing everything from either **conda-forge** OR **anaconda**, but not both).

Comment: I have done it couple of times but turns out I had to update my ubuntu gcc. After updating related packages I created a new env, now it works.